# AUTOSAR_Car Wakeup meaning

Tags: autosar

What is the meaning and use cases of **Car Wakeup** which is described in the specification of the communication system.
(`AUTOSAR_SWS_CANNetworkManagement` and ...)

There parameter descriptions, but there is no definition of the word.

Answer (score 1):

I can only speculate about your background in automotive communication, so please forgive me for starting at the basics.

The point of network management is to switch off communication networks that are not needed at a certain point in time. Colloquially speaking, you put those networks to sleep.

The switch-off can very well extend to the entire vehicle, or the vast majority of communication buses on a vehicle.

Of course, at some point the communication busses are needed again, and for this purpose, you "wake them up".

Comment: thank you for your answer.

I was recognized as follows.
・Not a Wakeup of one place (a unique communication bus).
・you start the whole function (to start a plurality of communication bus).For example, for the car keys, such as the case of transition from the ACC to START.